# How do I put a div over a specific line of a p?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a < p > tag full of text.  When rendered to the page its displayed in 5 lines.  I want to  style and position a < div > tag to highlight a given line without needing to touch the < p > tag or its contents, preferably using jQuery.

So the markup looks like

```
<p>one fish two fish red fish zoo fish fifth fish</p>
```

And rendered looks like

one fish
two fish
red fish
zoo fish
fifth fish

And I want a transparent red div on top of <strike>"red fish"</strike> line 3.

I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas.

In response to Matt Burland's questions:
I'm to create a function which, given an element P and a line number, places a colored box over that line as rendered.

The p could be rendered as any number of lines.

The window size is fixed so thats one thing I don't have to worry about.

Other functionality depends on the DOM of the page.  I can insert a div a tag but not much else.

Comment: You have tried anything, but can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: In general this is just not the sort of thing that an HTML/CSS rendering system lends itself to doing easily.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to touch the `<p>` tag? The normal approach would be to use an unordered list and simply put a background color on the list item to highlight.

Comment: `I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas.` - At least you're honest.

Comment: @MattBurland .. Was thinking the same exact thing.

Comment: `span` wouldn't work?

Comment: So what's your actual requirement here? You want a div over just the text `red fish` or you want it on the third line? Will it always be rendered as five lines? What if somebody resizes their browser? And what's your aversion to "touching the P"?

Comment: One good suggestion might be to post a question on StackOverflow without doing anything yourself and hope that someone there will do all the work for you.  What do you think?

Comment: Your issue/request is hazy at best. This is horribly low quality considering you have 2K rep

Comment: Maybe he wants the "Peer Pressure" badge?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I know, right? A new user would be a little more understandable; but 2k isn't exactly a noob.

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to criticize him so much for not showing any work. When SO is flooded with "how do I AJAX", a question with countless tutorials around, there's reason to be annoyed. Still, some novices could spend quite some time thinking on a problem like this without thinking up a proper solution, especially if they're less experienced with CSS, or JavaScript-based styling/positioning. Finding a tutorial might not be obvious either if you don't know the terms, or what technologies you'd use.

Comment: Excellent point @Katana314 you should point out this unfairness on [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/h6qe4/)

**JS**

```
$p = $('p').first();
$pHeight = $p.height()/5;
$pTop = $p.offset().top+(2*$pHeight);
$p.after('<div id="IvetriednothingandImalloutofideas" style="height:'+$pHeight+'px;top:'+$pTop+'px">');
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    outline:1px solid #ccc;
    width:60px; 
}

#IvetriednothingandImalloutofideas {
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: 1+ Excellent `id` name.

Comment: This looks like what I need, but is there a way to determine the number of lines being rendered by the p for the "/5" part?

Answer (score 0):

It's an really bad idea to do it like this. As other have told a list element is the proper way to do it. But If you need to keep the P intact you can set the line-height and do the math to place an div our whatever you want as overlay.

CSS:

```
line-height: 22px;
```

JS:

```
var pHeight = $('p').height();
var lineHeight = parseInt($('p').css('line-height'));
var selectedLine = 3;
$('#overlay').css('top', -Math.abs(selectedLine * lineHeight));
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVxdJ/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depend on formatting (line positions may change etc.) *and* you don't want to change the original `<P>`, you can clone it - highlight required text and superimpose cloned one over original one:

**HTML**

```
<p id="text">one fish two fish red fish zoo fish fifth fish</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#text {
    width:50px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color:red    
}
```

**JS**

```
var $text = $('#text');
var match = "red fish";

var $newtext = $text.clone().html($text.html().replace(match, '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>'))

$newtext.appendTo('body').offset($text.offset())
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/j4UfM/1/

You can remove highlighted copy as needed.